# 3.3V step up to 5V using BJT

Tags: arduino, bjt, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

I'm using an Arduino Blend Micro with outputs that provide only 3.3V and I need to control a MOSFET that needs 5V on its gate. Can I step up the voltage from 3.3V to 5V using a single BJT?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - what MOSFET would you like to activate with 3.3 volts (preferably) and we'll see if indeed it does need 5 volts to activate it. What load is the MOSFET controlling (voltage and current) and what speed do you wish to activate it at? What power supplies do you have available?

Comment: I'm using a CSD19535 but actually I'm using a summer opamp to add the 5V I need to a point between two mosfet acting as a switch for my coil. The current in my coil is about 20A with 16V. The speed is not really important, it's only to choose which coil I want to measure. Any power supply. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you need at least 8 volts to drive that transistor reliably. I have no idea what the summing amp is meant to be doing nor what the rest of that sentence means - show a diagram if you want more help is my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current in my coil is about 20A with 16V. The speed is not really
>   important, it's only to choose which coil I want to measure. Any power
>   supply.

Try this type of BJT interface to your MOSFET: -

[image]

The "switch" is just your 3.3 volt logic level input - feed it into Rb (maybe 470 ohms). Rc should be a couple of kohm and V2 should ideally be no less than 9 volts but it's likely the 16 volt that feeds your coil is fine. Make sure your coil (the load) has a reverse protection diode else your MOSFET will quickly die. If you think that the 16 volt rail may get a little higher, consider putting a zener diode across the BJT to protect the MOSFET gate from over-voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much. The signal won't be inverted with this type of configuration? Also, I've contacted you on Facebook.

Comment: Yes, the signal will be inverted - if this is a problem, add an inverter between logic output and base resistor.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/mMd8Nv) I think this would work, am I right? Thanks again :)

Comment: 5 volts isn't enough to drive the MOSFET on properly - please do consider using the 16 volt power rail as the feed for the BJT before the MOSFET. Look at the circuit I showed and read my explanation again and maybe please do justify why you think 5 volts is sufficient to drive the MOSFET gate. I don't want to have to walk around this again so take your time reading and checking.

Comment: Why do I need more than 5V ? Considering the Vgs(th) is 2.7V. What about this mosfet ? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQP30N06L-1009543.pdf

Comment: I need the 5V source (VS3) by an Arduino micro that provide 3.3V only.

Comment: Look at page 1 of the data sheet - look at the picture bottom left and ask yourself if 5 volts is enough - it isn't especially when you factor in temperature rises and that that graph is just "typical". I don't follow what that other picture is.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I step up the voltage from 3.3V to 5V using a single BJT?

We don't know what *your* capabilities are, but this can be done.  It is particularly easy if 5 V power is available.

**However**, you should really be looking at the overall problem to see if this conversion is really necessary.  You say you want to drive a FET.  Why not use a FET that switches on well enough with just 3.3 V gate drive?  What about a BJT?

Step back and look at the overall problem.